# Redirect filepointer to string in C/C++

Tags: c++, python, c, matlab

MATLAB allows saving variables to files via a closed-source library, that e.g. exposes the following functions:

```
FILE *matGetFp(MATFile *mfp);
MATFile *matOpen(const char *filename, const char *mode);
```

Is there a way in C/C++ that would allow me to redirect what would be written to disk into a string?

Would it be possible to redirect the `FILE` pointer?
The "constructor" unfortunately only takes a filename, not a Filepointer, in which case I'd have gone for pipes...

Basically I would like to achieve something similar to what python provides with the `StringIO` class, to be able serialize objects without the need of disk I/O.

I'm sorry if this does not completely fit into SO, but I didn't manage to find anything on this and guessed that I could get a quick "not possible" here, if this can't be done...

Comment: `C/C++` is undefined behavior.

Comment: Not entirely sure what you're looking for. Are you referring to the ability to use printf("%s", some_string) except instead of going to stdout it goes somewhere else?

Comment: You have to write your own serialization method that works with streams. Then you can use stringstream, fstream, ...

Comment: @JonahNelson other functions from the `mat...` library serialize MATLAB objects by writing them to the specified file/filepointer. Ideally I would like get whatever that `MATFile` usually writes to disk in a string/char buffer.

Answer (score 1):

In a word, no.

As [the documentation](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/apiref/matfileapi.html) states: "MATFile is a C language opaque type." Under the covers, the thing that you want to reassign/intercept *might* be a raw C file pointer, a handle to an HDF5 object, or maybe even something else. Depending on the MAT-file mode (version 4-or-earlier, version 7.3-or-later, or some other version) different parts of the implementation will be used, leading to different serializations.

I'm not sure why you would want to find out what *would* get written to disk and store it as a string, but you can always write it to disk and then read the bytes back in using low-level file I/O routines: `fopen()`, `fread()`, etc. But by that point you're basically working on reverse engineering the .mat file format.

Comment: I don't want to "find out" anything - as you say I can read it from disk at any time. Besides, there is no need in reverse-engineering, the mat-format is publicly documented by The Mathworks. I was playing with the idea of trying to set up an object database similar to `pickle` in python, which would require a serialization method for all sorts of matlab-objects, which mat-files obviously are.

Comment: Last but not least: I speculated it might be possible to redirect/manipulate the pure C `FILE` pointer, not mess with the `MATFile`. On Linux I might have tried a named pipe, on windows these don't seem to exist in the same manner...